# Problem with converting JSF1.2 applicationto JSF2.2 Glassfish deployment error: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408:

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4

I am in the process of trying to convert a suite of applicationss from JSF1.2 to JSF2.2. I have successfully converted 2 but am having a problem with the third. When I try to deploy it to GlassFish 4.1, I get the following errors from the GF console:

```
    Severe:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Inject public synchronized org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.DefaultBeanLocator.add(Injector)
  at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.DefaultBeanLocator.add(DefaultBeanLocator.java:0)
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
```

The program and its dependdencies are huge so I don't want to enter it all here, but here is the annotations I am using for the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="projectbean")
@SessionScoped
public class ProjectCreatorBean implements Serializable, ClientCreatorAware {
```

Any idea of what I should be looking for?This really has me stumped.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: What package are you using? Note that `javax.faces.bean` annotations are deprecated.

Comment: In addition, it looks like you may be using a combination of Weld (a CDI implementation) and Sisu (a Sonatype dependency injection container used almost exclusively with Maven's internals and rarely seen in the wild).  Mixing two dependency injection frameworks rarely ends well.

Comment: We are using JSF2.2,because we have glassfish 4.1 which is not compatible with JSF2.3. Where would I find the Sisu dependency.